# coding a deconvolution using python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, ifft, deconvolution

Before I begin I have to tell you that I have zero knowledge about DSP in python.
I want to deconvolute two sound signals using python so that I can extract the room impulse response, the input signal being a sinesweep and the output a record of it.
I wrote a piece of code but it didn't work, I've been trying for too long and really without results.
Can someone please help me with a code that calculate the FFT of the input and output then calculate h the iFFT of their fraction and plot it.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code that you tried so far?

Comment: Have you checked what's in scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html ?

Comment: you will learn nothing by copy N pasting a supplied answer ... take the problem apart and solve one step at a time

Comment: Hey Scott, I am not specialized in coding or IT, I just stuck on that with my project, I've been trying for 4 days now and no chance, and I have to hand it by Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

[Deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) is an ill-posed tough problem in presence of noise and spatially-variant blurring. I assume you have a non spatially variant problem, as far as you are using FFTs, so you can use [restoration module](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html) from skimage python package (instead of programming the algorithm at low level with FFTs).

Here you can study a [code example](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_restoration.html) with one of the implemented methods in restoration module.

I recommend you to read [O'Leary et al. book](http://bookstore.siam.org/fa03/) if you want to learn more. All authors of this book have more advanced books about this great topic.